# gdscript global variable value not changing after get_tree().reload_current_scene()

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

I wanted the variable

> first_playthrough

to become `false` so when the scene reloads, it won't show the text **"Hello from Number Guesser"** anymore. But it's still showing it.

Therefore, it's either: it never became `false`, or that it became `false`, but then went back to `true`.

The shortened version of the code:

```
extends Node

var first_playthrough = true

func _ready():
  # this is here so it will show the message
  first_playthrough_checker()

func first_playthrough_checker():
  # problem here is that, the message below still shows even though i thought i set it to 'false' already.
  if first_playthrough == true:
    text_printer("Hello from Number Guesser!\n\n")

func _restart_game():
  #I've tried everywhere else. Thought it would work here. i was wrong.
  get_tree().reload_current_scene()
  first_playthrough = false
```

One solution would be a persistent data storage.
But maybe for a simple game like this one, it isn't needed anymore?
What am i doing wrong here?

I'll post the whole script if needed.

Comment: Sorry, you mean you manually put in "false" after the (`==`) comparison operator (not shown above), and it still prints the message? Have you tried using `===`? If that doesn't work, I could probably help if you posted more code, yes.

Comment: Nevermind, I see now. It seems you are correct, it is never getting set `false`. I will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: As I thought. The solution you are looking for involves the use of a singleton to properly update the value of the variable globally. Unfortunately the projects I have done thus far have not required the use of singletons, so I am relatively inexperienced with them. Your question has prompted me to learn, however. If I figure it out before you do, I'll post my solution.

Comment: Your comment has inclined me to learn singletons too. Thanks for commenting! :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for posting that answer - Its already helping me understand better.

Answer (score 2):

Building on an answer from a different site where i posted the question as well.

After creating the singleton **globals** where `first_playthrough` is declared, i replaced all instances of the variable on the script into `globals.first_playthrough`.

So in the *shortened version* of the code, this looks like:

```
    extends Node

    # removed the declaration here already, since it's already declared in globals.gd

    func _ready():
      # this is here so it will show the message
      first_playthrough_checker()

    func first_playthrough_checker():
      # message below doesn't show anymore after globals.first_playthrough becomes false.
      if globals.first_playthrough:
        text_printer("Hello from Number Guesser!\n\n")

    func _restart_game():
      #I haven't tested it but i suspect the line after reloading the scene will create a memory leak?
      #So i changed globals.first_playthrough's value before reloading the scene instead.
      globals.first_playthrough = false
      get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

The script works as intended now.

By learning to use **singletons**, i learned that:

- Declaring a variable global to the class even in a single script
  project doesn't make it actually global.
- An object is only global if it is declared in the project as so.
- I should keep in mind that I'm still using a framework.
- With gdscript, I have 3 options to store persistent information. 2 of which are most recommended.

*Singleton documentation link:*
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html?highlight=autoload